# Why did R' Yehoshua scold the walls of the shul?

Tags: talmud-gemara

> "Rabbi Eliezer then said to them: If the halakha is with me, the walls of the study hall will prove it. The walls of the study hall leaned inward and began to fall. ***Rabbi Yehoshua scolded the walls*** and said to them: If Torah scholars are contending with each other in matters of halakha, what is the nature of your involvement in this dispute?.." [Bava_Metzia.59b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.59b.3?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

In the famous argument, R' Yehoshua didn't intervene with the Cherub tree or the stream, however, he scolded the walls. I couldn't find comments on that.

Why did he suddenly care about the walls? Why after the two miracles did he expect the walls to behave differently upon R' Eliezer's request?

Comment: The same reason you might ignore all the warning letters that you owe money, but you’ll wake up when they come to seize your house.

Comment: @Alex Right, once his life was in danger, you say?

Comment: Not necessarily his life, but at the very least the study hall was going to collapse.

Comment: @Alex BTW was R' Eliezer there? Why would he endanger his and others' lives?

Comment: I suppose an interesting interpretation would be that all the rabbis were in the study hall and R. Eliezer was trying to wipe them all out (no more majority).

Comment: So they wouldn't fall on them and they would all die (No such ramifications existed with the tree and stream)?